# MAUI image crop example and display it

Tags: c#, maui

I need to crop and display an image using **ImageCropper.MAUI**, I can't get the image to show up and I get image not found exception.

https://github.com/jbowmanp1107/ImageCropper.Maui
[image: Exception]

I have added code where I can get the image path after cropped.

```
ImageCrop.Success = (imageFile) =>
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () =>
            {
                imageFile = imageFile.Replace(@"/my_images/Pictures/", "");

                var _d = FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory;
             

                var pathTemp = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures), imageFile);
        //"/my_images/Pictures/cropped2795616814194734447.png"
                //cropped2795616814194734447.png
                //cropped9006441269099458689.png
                if (File.Exists(pathTemp))
                {
                    //Check for file exists or not
                }

                path = pathTemp;
                resultImage.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(pathTemp);
                await Empty();
            });
    }
```

I have also attached the path of image as below in emulator.

[Image path in emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lijVh.jpg)

Comment: from error, you are trying to read/get image from directory which still doesn't exits or haven't been created.

Comment: instead of link to exception, draft the exception to the question and also share the code block which you had tried.

Comment: please read [ask] before posting.  Posts should contains the relevant code, properly formatted.  A link to an external repo or a screenshot of the code is NOT acceptable.  Details about errors or exceptions should also be included, properly formatted, and not as images

Comment: I had to heavily edit your question to make it more understandable, if however, you feel that my edit changes the question you are asking, feel free to rollback or edit your question.  If you want people to be able to help you, you should include relevant bits of code as it is impossible to help you just by looking at the exception that you are seeing.

Comment: @ShashankShekhar I have updated the code as well as path in emulator of image, please check.

Comment: Is there any solutions try attached examples from github l.